# Search for text in one column within a string in another column

Tags: r

Newbie to R here. Been searching this forum to try and find a way to search for text within a string in the same row of data. I've used grepl before, but I can't get it to look down a column and apply the check for each row. I feel like this is an easy solution, but I've spent a few hours on it and can't seem to get it.

Basically I have something like column 1 below and need it to check if the text in column 2 is within column one, then return true or false in a new column.

```
column 1         column2     result
Target_US_Toy    _US_        TRUE
Target_CA_Toy    _MX_        FALSE
Target_NZ_Toy    _NZ_        TRUE
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str_detect` from the `stringr` pacakge:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(df1$column1, df1$column2)

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

or using only base R combining `grepl` with apply:

```
apply(df1,1, function(x){
  grepl(x[2], x[1])
})
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I've mainly been using dplyr and haven't gotten to stringr yet. Should probably take my next course on that

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `stringr`.

First, let's create a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = c("Target_US_Toy", "Target_CA_Toy"),
                 column2 = c("_US_", "_NZ_"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next, we create a new column called `result`:

```
library(stringr)
df$result = str_detect(string = df$column1, pattern = df$column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grepl` with `Map`

```
unlist(Map(grepl, df$column2, df$column1))
```

**Output**:

```
 #_US_  _MX_  _NZ_ 
 #TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The base method would be to use `mapply` to deliver a "parallel" set of arguments to a function that is not vectorized in one or more of its argument positions:

```
dat$ result <- mapply(grepl, dat$column2, dat$column1)

> dat
        column1 column2 result
1 Target_US_Toy    _US_   TRUE
2 Target_CA_Toy    _MX_  FALSE
3 Target_NZ_Toy    _NZ_   TRUE
```