# Does part of one column exist in another? R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id_1=c('888046309', '888046309', '888046309', '888046309', '003046309', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132', '465798132'), 
                 id_2=c('0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309', '0003046309'))
```

and I would like to create a column that would indicate where **a part** of `id_2` is present in `id_1`.

I tried this from this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505466/r-column-check-if-contains-value-from-another-column)

```
i <- sapply(seq_along(df$id_2), function(i) grepl(df$id_2[i], df$id_1[i]))

df$flag <- c("No", "Yes")[i + 1L]
```

and flag had all NO values even though you can see that 46309 is present in both `id_1` & `id_2`.

I then tried this from this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933361/search-for-text-in-one-column-within-a-string-in-another-column)

```
df$flag_2 <- str_detect(df$id_1, df$id_2)
```

And I got FALSEs for `flag_2`

Finally I tried this, and like `flag_2`, I got all FALSEs for `flag_3`.

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(flag_3 = c('No', 'Yes')[1+str_detect(id_1, as.character(id_2))])
```

Can these suggestions be edited so that it can indicate if some part of `id_2` is present in `id_1`?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28261825/13513328) helps

Comment: the function listed at the end of this suggestion only allows for situations where the leading numbers are the same. so thanks but it didn't work.

Comment: So, just to be clear, 1 character overlap would still need to be marked as "Yes"?

Comment: good question. How about four or more?

Comment: This answer seems to work for your question, albeit you need to add `nchar( ) >= 4`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702045/5805670

Comment: i'm really sorry @slamballais but I dont know how one would go about applying this to a dataframe

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) nchar(larsub(x)) > 4)` . Edit: Do note that this solution takes ANY 4 characters, they don't have to be subsequent. If this is not what you want, maybe try and put all the requirements that you can think of into the opening post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `adist` which basically calculates the cost to convert one string into another. Define a `th`reshold how much replacement you want to allow and set a respective flag.

```
df$d <- t(apply(df[c('id_1', 'id_2')], 1, adist))[,2]
df
#         id_1       id_2 d
# 1  888046309 0003046309 4
# 2  888046309 0003046309 4
# 3  888046309 0003046309 4
# 4  888046309 0003046309 4
# 5  003046309 0003046309 1
# 6  465798132 0003046309 9
# 7  465798132 0003046309 9
# 8  465798132 0003046309 9
# 9  465798132 0003046309 9
# 10 465798132 0003046309 9
# 11 465798132 0003046309 9
# 12 465798132 0003046309 9
# 13 465798132 0003046309 9

th <- nchar(df$id_2)[1] - 2
df$flag <- with(df, ifelse(d > th, 1, 0))
df
#         id_1       id_2 d flag
# 1  888046309 0003046309 4    0
# 2  888046309 0003046309 4    0
# 3  888046309 0003046309 4    0
# 4  888046309 0003046309 4    0
# 5  003046309 0003046309 1    0
# 6  465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 7  465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 8  465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 9  465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 10 465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 11 465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 12 465798132 0003046309 9    1
# 13 465798132 0003046309 9    1
```

#### Combined

We can of course combine the two steps then it looks like this:

```
th <- 8  ## arbitrary
df <- within(df, flag <- t(apply(df[c('id_1', 'id_2')], 1, adist))[,2] < th)
df
#         id_1       id_2  flag
# 1  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
# 2  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
# 3  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
# 4  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
# 5  003046309 0003046309  TRUE
# 6  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 7  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 8  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 9  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 10 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 11 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 12 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
# 13 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
```

Comment: thank you @jay.sf    my real dataset has these two variables at columns 7 and 8. if i were to take this solution to it, would i replace 1 w 7 and 2 with 8? i tried that and got this error 'MARGIN' does not match dim(X)  with the d variable

Comment: @tangerine7199 Use the two column names as subset in the `apply`, see update.

Comment: great! Thank you!

Comment: @tangerine7199 You can combine it to an one-liner, see update.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you have in mind, I tried it and I got some encouraging results, but there is still room for improvement. For this I erased 2 `0` from the `id_2` maybe it wasn't a good call but it facilitate fuzzy matching here.

```
df$flag <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) agrepl(substr(df$id_2[x], 2, nchar(df$id_2[x])), 
                                                 df$id_1[x], max.distance = 4))


df

        id_1       id_2  flag
1  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
2  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
3  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
4  888046309 0003046309  TRUE
5  003046309 0003046309  TRUE
6  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
7  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
8  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
9  465798132 0003046309 FALSE
10 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
11 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
12 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
13 465798132 0003046309 FALSE
```

Comment: It doesn't generalize well to new data: `agrepl("8888", "8887", max.distance = 4)` returns `TRUE` (for any `max.distance` except `0`).

Comment: It should return `TRUE` for your example because they partial match. But if you try it with `grepl` the result is `FALSE`. I know this is not a very good solution but still have some `TRUE`s than all `FALSE`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was referencing to OPs requirement for >3 matching characters (see comments), but it seems they are happy with the answer.

Comment: No it's ok there are certainly better solutions than this as it only meets bare minimum of OP's requirements. But I thought it still better than no match. It should after all be tested on a larger data set.

Comment: @slamballais `agrepl` function has proven very useful to me but I don't know why it is not used very often by users.

Comment: Thank you for this! What if i wanted to do four or more? I tried max.distance >= 4)) and an error was produced: " Error in .amatch_bounds(max.distance) : object 'max.distance' not found "

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it could help somehow. The value you supply to `max.distance` should be an interger or a fraction of the pattern length. It cannot be a logical expression.